# Parser error on installing the remotipart gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, yard

I am using `RVM`, `Ruby v1.9.3-p125` and `Ruby on Rails v3.2.2`. On my Ubuntu server I am trying to install the [`remotipart v1.0.2`](https://github.com/leppert/remotipart) gem but I get the following error:

```
$ gem install remotipart -v 1.0.2
Successfully installed remotipart-1.0.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for remotipart-1.0.2...
Building YARD (yri) index for remotipart-1.0.2...
[error]: ParserSyntaxError: syntax error in `LICENSE`:(1,18): syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting $end
[error]: Stack trace:
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:517:in `on_parse_error'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:15:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:438:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:361:in `parse_in_order'

[error]: ParserSyntaxError: syntax error in `README.rdoc`:(1,1): syntax error, unexpected '='
[error]: Stack trace:
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:517:in `on_parse_error'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:15:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:438:in `parse'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/yard-0.7.5/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:361:in `parse_in_order'

Installing RDoc documentation for remotipart-1.0.2...

$
```

What does it means? Is the `remotipart` gem correctly installed? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try installing without the documentation to see if it installs correctly then. That would isolate the problem to the documentation.

```
gem install remotipart -v 1.0.2 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```